# How to get document.documentMode property from WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a very simple forms application with WebBrowser control on the form which I want to use to debug rendering issues, especially which documentType is used by the browser.
When I navigate in IE to the website, it's easy - I open up the JS console and type `document.documentType` and get value.

How can I achieve the same from the C# and `WebBrowser` control?

I have tried:

```
private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (webBrowser1.Document != null)
    {
        var document = webBrowser1.Document;
        mshtml.IHTMLDocument doc = (mshtml.IHTMLDocument) document.DomDocument;   
    }
}
```

But the `doc` doesn't seem to surface `documentMode` property easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast the [`Document.DomDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.domdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) to `dynamic` and get the document mode using [`documentMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/cc288665(v=vs.85)) property:

```
var documentMode = ((dynamic)(webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument)).documentMode;
```

Just make sure you are using the code in [`DocumentCompleted`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event of `WebBrowser`.

Comment: JFYI, `documentMode` is a member of `IHTMLDocument6` interface.